# "io: postinst-must-call-ldconfig" when creating a package

Tags: package-management, packaging, deb

I'm trying to create an ubuntu .deb package for the (pretty awesome) [Io Language](http://www.iolanguage.com/). I am not the developer of that language, so I'm not familiar with [its sourcecode](https://github.com/stevedekorte/io) yet. This is my first attempt at creating a .deb file.

In order to create the .deb, I'm following these instructions:

http://www.webupd8.org/2010/01/how-to-create-deb-package-ubuntu-debian.html

So far I've been able to create a .deb file (io_2010.06.01-1_amd64.deb) and a changes file (io_201.06.01-1_amd64.changes). I'm using lintian to check the changes file, and it reports an issue I don't know how to resolve:

```
$ lintian -Ivi io_2010.06.01-1_amd64.changes

... (lots of messages)

I: io: no-symbols-control-file usr/lib/libiovmall.so
I: io: no-symbols-control-file usr/lib/libgarbagecollector.so
I: io: no-symbols-control-file usr/lib/libbasekit.so
E: io: postinst-must-call-ldconfig usr/lib/libiovmall.so
N: 
N:    The package installs shared libraries in a directory controlled by the
N:    dynamic library loader. Therefore, the package must call "ldconfig" in
N:    its postinst script.
N:    
N:    Refer to Debian Policy Manual section 8.1.1 (ldconfig) for details.
N:    
N:    Severity: serious, Certainty: certain
N: 
N: Removing /tmp/OYuNShEHYz ...
```

I've read the [debian manual 8.8 section](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-sharedlibs.html). I think I understand what the problem is (I need to make sure that ldconfig is invoked "somewhere", possibly on a place called "posinst") but I don't know *how* to resolve it (i.e. where this "posinsts" file is and how should I change it).

The current way of installing Io in Ubuntu is basically running `sudo make install` and then `sudo ldconfig`. Maybe the makefile should be modified so ldconfig is called from it? I don't know.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is you packaging located somewhere? Seeing at least your `debian/rules` file might shed some light on your specific problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`postinst` is a maintainer script that you can add to the `debian` directory. Most straight forward packages shouldn't require the maintainer to create this file. Debhelper will automatically create it for you in the binary package. See both the [New Maintainer's Guide](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/dother.en.html#maintscripts) and [Debian Policy Manual's](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-maintainerscripts.html) sections on maintainer scripts.

Comment: This was it. The debian folder had a postinst.ex file meant to be an example. I renamed it to postinst, modified it so that ldconfig was called when the installation was done correctly, and the warning is gone now. Thanks!